# webp image display black background instead of transparency

Tags: php

When upload `png` image and convert into `webp` image using `rossell-dk plugin`. means it display black background instead of transparent background.

```
$success = WebPConvert\WebPConvert::convert($pathToImages, $pathToWebpImages, [
            // It is not required that you set any options - all have sensible defaults.
            // We set some, for the sake of the example.
            'quality' => 'auto',
            'max-quality' => 90,
            'converters' =>  [ 'gd', 'imagick', 'wpc', 'ewww']/*,
            'skip-pngs'=>"0"*/
            //'converters' => ['cwebp','webp', 'gd', 'imagick', 'wpc', 'ewww'],  
            // Specify conversion methods to use, and their order
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done a lot of research and testing and unfortunately, it seems that all hope is lost for retaining alpha channel for webp on old Gd. [Here is why](https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-convert/issues/238#issuecomment-545928597).

Can you tell me the version of Gd and PHP? It is available in the conversion log. Or simply run this:

```php
<?php
echo 'PHP version: ' . PHP_VERSION . '<br>';
echo 'GD Version: ' . gd_info()["GD Version"] . '<br>';
```

Switch conversion method if others are available. Or upgrade Gd. But Gd is not very good for converting pngs to webp anyway as it doesn't support lossless webp.

Answer (score 1):

Old Gd versions does not handle transparency. More info: https://github.com/rosell-dk/webp-express/issues/374